# The m value affects imputed values

Tags: multiple-imputation, mice

The imputed data I have from

```
imputedata <- mice(data, m=2, seed = 12345, maxit = 10)
```

are different from the first 2 imputed data sets obtained from

```
imputedata <- mice(data, m=5, seed = 12345, maxit = 10)
```

I was not expecting this difference and was unable to find details explaining it in https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v045i03, a published document of mice() for version 2.9. The document does state that "it executes m streams in parallel," the meaning of which was not obvious for me.  My understanding is that all imputed data sets are based on one same imputation model with additional randomization mechanism in data simulation. So, the difference might be due to how the randomization seed is applied in the process.  Would appreciate any insight about how the randomization is done to make the 2 data sets different as mentioned at the beginning.

Comment: I'll bet that if you were to run either of those commands again, you would get yet seven new imputed datasets, too: that's the nature of "multiple imputations for incomplete multivariate data by Gibbs sampling."  The documentation states that `m` is the "Number of multiple imputations."  It's hard to know what one could add to that description.  What kind of answers might you be looking for?

Comment: @whuber - Actually, running both statements a second time reproduced the same data sets as the first time, which was my expectation.  So, my question was: It seems multiple imputation data sets are generated at the same time with some correlation among them, as opposed to one data set at a time without affecting each other.

Comment: Sorry--I overlooked the fact you are explicitly setting the seed in each run.  What is only implied so far is that you seem to expect `mice` to be generating the imputed datasets one at a time, so that (say) the first one will always be the same no matter how many datasets you request, provided you always start with the same seed. But if you watch the output of `mice` while it is operating, it should already be clear that this is not how it works. Thus I have to ask you again: what is your question about "affect imputation" actually trying to get at?

Comment: @whuber - Thank you for confirming that  first 2 data sets are meant to differ between the two R commands.  As you stated, I did not expect this way; and, the mice() document  says not much other than it executes  m streams in parallel,  It might have been obvious to others, but I would like to understand the relationship among these data sets other than that each is based on random drawing from one same prediction model.  I  assume this has to do with how the randomization seed is applied in the simulation process.

Comment: That's a reasonable and interesting question.  It would be good if you could edit your post so that it asks that question explicitly.